# How to save the content of tinymce in sql database?

Tags: asp.net, sql, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce in a website and I want to save texts and images ,written and inserted in the editor, to the database.
Does tinymce have a function or something for that?

I checked out the tinymce website, but couldn't find the answer.
Can anyone give me a hint or something please?

Comment: post data using a button.

Comment: @Nithin How?! can you provide an example please?